# Changing cfform values with javascript for dynamic bind output

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

CFM

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function toggleV(value){
        document.getElementById('blah').value = value;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<cfform name="coolfrm">
    <cfinput type="hidden" name="blah" id="blah" value="default">
    <a onclick="toggleV('anothervalue')" style="cursor:pointer;">click Me</a>
</cfform>

<cfdiv bind="cfc:TestCFC.func({coolfrm:blah})"></cfdiv>

</body>
</html>
```

CFC

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cfscript>
        remote function func(simpleString){
            return simpleString;
        }
    </cfscript>
</cfcomponent>
```

What I expect this code to do is change the text in the cfdiv from "default" to "anothervalue".

This doesn't work the way I think it should, and I would like to know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition from: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html

> The onchange event occurs when a control loses the input focus and its
>   value has been modified since gaining focus.

The change event isn't firing correctly when you modify the field programmatically.

Solve this by changing the JavaScript function slightly:

```
function toggleV(value){
    document.getElementById('blah').value = value;
    ColdFusion.Event.callBindHandlers('blah',null,'change');
}
```

Comment: Credit goes to the CFJediMaster on this: http://www.coldfusionjedi.com/index.cfm/2009/7/8/Forcing-ColdFusion-to-recognize-changes-made-to-data-used-for-Ajax-bindings