# How can I bind cfdiv to a CFC that maintains state?

Tags: coldfusion, cfc

CFM

```
<html>

<head>

<title>Test Page</title>

</head>

<body>

    <cfform>
        <cfinput type="text" name="input">
    </cfform>

    <cfscript>
        calc = CreateObject("component", "TestCFC");
    </cfscript>

    <cfdiv bind="cfc:TestCFC.func({input})"></cfdiv>
    <cfdiv bind="cfc:TestCFC.func2()"></cfdiv>

    
</body>
</html>
```

CFC

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cfscript>
        this.output = '';
        
        remote function func(input){
            output = input;
            return output;  
        }
        remote function func2(){
            return output & ' Hello World.';    
        }
    </cfscript>
</cfcomponent>
```

Input:

> First Words:

Expected output

> First Words:
>
> First Words: Hello World.

Workarounds are welcome.

Comment: Why not just pass `{input} into` both functions? I am guessing there is something more to it ... can you elaborate?

Comment: @Leigh Yup, I updated my answer after it became clear 2 questions were being asked.

Comment: @Leigh Let's say I have some user input that results in a "dynamic" user input based object, that object is a result of func(input) and now I just want to retrieve 1 one of the properties of that object func2(you can also think of func2 as getFName() or something like that), how do I do that.

Comment: I clarified this below: Events are not fired on the server, so if you are trying to bind to a method that access a stateful variable, it's not going to know "when to update" and will remained unchanged. You need to move the event logic to the client where the cfdiv lines are.

Comment: @Shawn Holmes I acknowledged this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cfdiv bindings are single requests to the CFC--state is not cached or maintained between them. Access to internal shared scopes like VARIABLES ends at the return of the request. You must build/maintain this state manually.

Step 1: Put your CFC in the same directory as an Application.cfc that enables SessionManagement:

```
<cfset this.sessionManagement = true />
<cfset this.sessionTimeout = createTimeSpan(0,20,0,0) />
```

Step 2: Change your CFC so that the intended variable that will persist between each individual request resides in the SESSION scope:

```
<cfcomponent>

    <cfset session.output = '' />
```

Step 3: Write your functions so that you read/write this stateful scope:

```
    remote function func(input){
        session.output = arguments.input;
        return session.output;
    }
```

Step 4:

Come up with a mechanism for your client to chain 'onchange' events across DIVs. It can be done any number of ways, but must be done by you (it's not automatic) -- The quickest starting point would be to refer to your previous question about [binding dynamic events to multiple fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7652136/changing-cfform-values-with-javascript-for-dynamic-bind-output/7653617#7653617).

It's worth it to note that using a CFC to wrap a scope like SESSION should absolutely be done with care, use protections where possible (ie `StructKeyExists(SESSION,'output')` ), as different types of requests (web vs. service) invoke shared scopes differently (or not at all), and you also have timeouts to worry about.

Comment: Yes but that doesn't give me my expected output.

Comment: That's because func2() is broken. You are referring to a variable within it that doesn't exist (output) -- you are actually asking two questions: 1) Can you bind a CFC method to a field? Yes. It's in my answer. 2) Why aren't I getting the expected output? -- You are assuming your CFC has a shared scope-scope your arguments and pass them appropriately from method to method.

Comment: I know the code, which is for illustration purposes, is broken. Essentially I want to bind to an object, that has an instance, so that the output variable's value is retained across all of the methods.

Comment: "1) Can you bind a CFC method to a field? Yes. It's in my answer." is what you said. My question actually looks like this "Is it possible to bind to an object to a cfdiv?". Then you said "You are assuming your CFC has a shared scope-scope your arguments and pass them appropriately from method to method.", to which I reply "That's why I want an object".

Comment: Can't. You can absolutely share an instance variable in the CFC (hint: use the VARIALBLES scope in the pseudo-constructor), problem is: there is no server-side event that fires when that shared variable changes by another set. Even if you were to wrap a getter around it, binding that getter method to the 2nd cfdiv will not cause it to update automatically. So while you can maintain state, changes to those hidden values are not going to propagate with change events. You'll have to tie the events together in the client (ie. bind the 2nd div to the results of the 1st)

Comment: "You'll have to tie the events together in the client (ie. bind the 2nd div to the results of the 1st)" if you decide to change your answer could you please include a code example of how something like this might be accomplished preceded by your explanation of why my way won't work, I think this would make a really good answer.

Comment: It is an entirely different question: How can I bind cfdiv to a CFC that maintains state? I'm not sure if you want to create a new question or modify this question's title.